# Tkinter returning ".!entry" instead of text contents of the Entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, grid, widget

I was making a program that takes and entry and returns it with tkinter and a tkinter `grid`, but when I tried to get the value of what was in the `Entry`, it didn't work!

I looked on the internet for solutions but none of them included a `grid` except this one: 
[Return values of Tkinter text entry, close GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032089/return-values-of-tkinter-text-entry-close-gui), but it's way too hard!

Here is my code so far:

```
# import tkinter module
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

# creating main tkinter window/toplevel
master = Tk()

# this will create a label widget
l1 = Label(master, text = "First:")
l2 = Label(master, text = "Second:")

# entry widgets, used to take entry from user
e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)
def input_():
    title = e1.get()
    body = e2.get()
    print(e1)
    print(e2)
# grid method to arrange labels in respective
# rows and columns as specified
l1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W, pady = 2)
l2.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W, pady = 2)
submit = Button(master, text="Submit", command=input_)

# this will arrange entry widgets
e1.grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = 2)
e2.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 2)
submit.grid(row = 3, column = 1, pady = 2)

# infinite loop which can be terminated by keyboard
# or mouse interrupt
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because in the `input` function, you are printing

```
print(e1)
print(e2)
```

which are the `Entry` objects. You might have been trying to print the `title` and `body`, which are being extracted, but unused.