# Problems of global variables with Python

Tags: python

I created a small program that shows a window and asks passwords, ids, to check if the user is saved in a database. If password is correct, then it affects `True` to a boolean named `mdp_valide` ('password_is_valid' in english) which was `False` before, and destroys the window of connexion. It's a function that changes that value, so I used a `global` statement at the top of the function. However, when it closes the window, the value `mdp_valide` is back to `False`
Here's some code to help you understand

First, the main program that will call the other function:

```
while 1:
    mdp_valide, utilisateur_en_cours = fenetre_connection(False, None)
    print ('in the main', mdp_valide, utilisateur_en_cours)
    if not mdp_valide:
        sys.exit()
    else :
        lancer_messagerie(utilisateur_en_cours)
```

Then, the function which is not working:

```
def fenetre_connection (mdp_val, utilisateur):
    mdp_valide = mdp_val
    utilisateur_en_cours = utilisateur

    root_co = Tk ()

    # .... Lots of stuff

    def verification():
        mdp_co = mot_de_passe.get()
        global mdp_valide
        global utilisateur_en_cours

        if mdp_co == recuperer_donnee_utilisateur (identifiant_utilisateur_co, 'mot_de_passe'): # check if the password is the one of the database

            print ('condition checked')
            mdp_valide = True
            utilisateur_en_cours = identifiant_utilisateur_co
            print ("before destroying : ", mdp_valide, utilisateur_en_cours)
            root_co.destroy()
            print ("after destroying : ", mdp_valide, utilisateur_en_cours)
        else:
            return 1

    Button(Frameboutons_co, text="Valider", font='Cambria', command = verification).pack(side=RIGHT) #Bouton qui verifie la validité du pseudo et du mot de passe


    root_co.mainloop()

    print ('before return : ', mdp_valide)

    return mdp_valide
```

Test :

```
before destroying:  True guil23
after destroying :  True guil23
before return :  False None
in the main : False None
```

The problem is here : the function verification () does change the value of mdp_valide into `True`, but after returning the value, it's back to `False`

Comment: I don't see `global mdp_valide` in the function `fenetre_connection`. That might be your problem.

Comment: Er I removed it, sorry. But it was in the original post. I  put it back

Comment: Actually, it was already there, but you might habe been mistaken by the wrong indentation. I corrected it

Comment: Here is a shorter version that illustrate the problem: https://repl.it/HDdW

Comment: This is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099908/python-tkinter-return-value-from-function-used-in-command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in `fenetre_connection`, `mdp_valide` is not global. So it is a local variable. Then in `verification`, you use `global mdp_valide`, so that one is a global variable.

When `verification` finishes, you return the local variable from `fenetre_connection`.

In python 3 you can use `nonlocal`: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement

In python 2, you can declare `mdp_valide` as global in `fenetre_connection` so that both variables are in the global scope, and therefore are the same

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working again. (I used the global because the nonlocal was a bit over complicated :) ).

Comment: But still, I don't understand how is that possible. Is not global supposed to take the variable which is somewhere "above" ?

Comment: @Guil23 - `global` does not mean "somewhere" above, but *specifically* at the module level.

Comment: As I had understood, when you have : [Spacename1 : somevariable, [Spacename2]], and you want to access somevariable within Spacename2, using global gives you that access

Comment: @Guil23 in your case, you had: a different `mdp_valide` in global and in `fenetre_connection` (local) (that would be connexion, btw). In `verification`, you are using the global one.

Comment: Okay, I think I've understood thanks. And for connection, as you can see I have not translated the names from French, that's why 'connection' with 'ct' :)

Comment: @Guil23 You may be surprised to find out that connexion (with an x) is the correct spelling in French ;)

Comment: oooh you're right ^^ I always think 'connexion' is english and 'connection' french whereas it's the contrary