# How to assign function return values to class variables within tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a simple GUI using tkinter in Python3. It allows the user to press a button which calls a function, `select_files`, that lets the user select a bunch of files. The function processes the files and outputs a tuple of three things that need to be assigned to class variables, say a, b, c, for further processing. These variables should be accessible to any function that I define inside the class.

I attempted the following, but I get `name 'self' is not defined` error. The function `select_files` is already defined and written in a separate .py file and I am importing it from the correct location. I'm relatively new to GUI programming and object-oriented programming in general.

I studied a similar question asked here: [python tkinter return value from function used in command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099908/python-tkinter-return-value-from-function-used-in-command), which was helpful in general, but couldn't help me with my specific problem.

Should these `self.a`, `self.b`, `self.c` variables appear under the `__init__()` method? If so, how do I assign them to the return values of `select_files` function? Also, would this make the function `open_files` unnecessary?

```
from ... import select_files
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.run_button()

    def open_files(self):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = select_files()

    print(self.a) #self is not defined error comes from here

    def run_button(self):
        self.button = tk.Button(root, text = 'run', command = self.open_files)
        self.button.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

EDIT: based on rassar's comment, I made the following change, and it works. The user can press the print button, and the object gets printed. Can someone now explain why `self.run_button()` and `self.print_button()` need to be in the init method?

```
class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.run_button()
        self.print_button()

    def open_files(self):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = select_files()

    def print_files(self):
        print(self.a)

    def run_button(self):
        self.button = tk.Button(root, text = 'run', command = self.open_files)
        self.button.pack()

    def print_button(self):
        self.button = tk.Button(root, text = 'print', command = self.print_files)
        self.button.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think your problem is that you are printing `self.a` outside a function body. You can’t access instance variables at the class level. You are setting `self.a` correctly. Where are you attempting to access it? You might need a global variable.

Comment: Should the problem statement be part of `open_files()`?  If yes, then indent the statement one more level will solve the error.

Comment: Thanks rassar. If I understand you correctly, self.a can ONLY be accessed from within another function in the class's body?

Comment: *" explain why self.run_button() and self.print_button() need to be in the init method?"*: It's uncommen to use a own `function` to create a `Button`. You can replace `self.run_button()` with the `def run_button(...` statements.