# I have problems when I try to put the text of the label from a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm doing a calculator with Python 3.8 and Visual Studio. I'm trying to print the result in the label on button click.

This is the error:

> Undefined variable 'resultado' pylint(undefined-variable) [37, 32]

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

r = Tk()
r.title("CALCULADORA")

def operar(num1, num2, signo):

    resultado = IntVar()

    if signo == "+":
        resultado = num1 + num2

    elif signo == "-":
        resultado = num1 - num2

    elif signo == "/":
        resultado = num1 / num2

    elif signo == "X":
        resultado = num1 * num2

    return resultado


textNumUno = Entry(r, width=7)
textNumUno.grid(row=0, column=0)

textOperacion = Entry(r, width=3)
textOperacion.grid(row=0, column=1)

textNumDos = Entry(r, width=7)
textNumDos.grid(row=0, column=2)

btn = Button(r, text="=", width=2, command=operar(textNumUno.get(), textNumDos.get(), textOperacion.get()))
btn.grid(row=0, column=3)

labelResultado = Label(r, text=resultado)
labelResultado.grid(row=0, column=4)

r.mainloop()
```

Comment: resultado is local variable inside `operar()` - you have to create it outside `operar()`

Comment: Read [Why is Button parameter “command” executed when declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared) and [return value from function used in command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13101037/7414759)

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes

---

`resultado` is local variable - you have to create it outside function

---

`IntVar()`, (`StringVar()`, etc.) is not normal variable and it needs `.get()`, `.set()` to work with this

```
resultado.set( int(num1) + int(num2) )

print( resultado.get() )
```

---

`Button` doesn't work like `input()` - it doesn't wait for your answer so `Label(   text=)` is created before you put text and press button. You can use `textvarable=` to assign `IntVar()` (`StringVar()`, etc.) and when you change value in IntVar then it will change text on Label.

---

`Button` will execute function later but it can't get result so using `return` in `operar` is useless.

---

`command=` need function name without `()` and arguments (so called `callback`) and later (when you press button) it will add `()` to this name to execute it. If you have to use function with arguments then you may use `lambda` to create function without arguments.

```
command=lambda:operar(textNumUno.get(), textNumDos.get(), textOperacion.get()))
```

---

`Entry` gives strings which you have to convert to `int()` (or `float()`)

---

```
#from tkinter import * # PEP8: not preferred
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def operar(num1, num2, signo):

    if signo == "+":
        resultado.set( int(num1) + int(num2) )

    elif signo == "-":
        resultado.set( int(num1) - int(num2) )

    elif signo == "/":
        resultado.set( int(num1) / int(num2) )

    elif signo in "*xX":
        resultado.set( int(num1) * int(num2) )

# --- main ---

r = tk.Tk()
r.title("CALCULADORA")

resultado = tk.IntVar()

textNumUno = tk.Entry(r, width=7)
textNumUno.grid(row=0, column=0)

textOperacion = tk.Entry(r, width=3)
textOperacion.grid(row=0, column=1)

textNumDos = tk.Entry(r, width=7)
textNumDos.grid(row=0, column=2)

btn = tk.Button(r, text="=", width=2, command=lambda:operar(textNumUno.get(), textNumDos.get(), textOperacion.get()))
btn.grid(row=0, column=3)

labelResultado = tk.Label(r, textvariable=resultado)
labelResultado.grid(row=0, column=4)

r.mainloop()
```

---

**BTW:** as for `import *` see [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with the `tkinter` syntax, but `text=resultado` looks like an issue. That variable is local to the `operar` function, so it doesn't make sense to call it globally