# Using my local variable outside of the function

Tags: python, function, tkinter

As I go deeper into my script I am faced with another problem.

I am using tkinter and tkcalendar together and have something like this:

[image]

I have a function set so that when you click the button "validez la date", it stores the date gotten from the `cal.getdate()` function from tkcalendar. The problem is I can't get to use that variable outside of the function.

Here is my function:

```py
def setdate():
    datechoisie = cal.get_date()
    datechoisie = datechoisie.replace("/", "-")
    datechoisie = datechoisie.split('-')
    datechoisie = "-".join(reversed(datechoisie))
    mylabel.config(text="Date validée !")
    print(datechoisie)
    return(datechoisie)
```

The complexity is the `datechoisie` variable only gets a value if the corresponding button is pressed.

How can I make this work or is there a better way?

Edit: I have tried setting `datechoisie` as a global like mentionned:

```
def setdate():
    global datechoisie1
    datechoisie = cal.get_date()
    datechoisie = datechoisie.replace("/", "-")
    datechoisie = datechoisie.split('-')
    datechoisie = "-".join(reversed(datechoisie))
    mylabel.config(text="Date validée !")
    datechoisie1 = datechoisie

print(datechoisie1)
```

I still get `datechoisie1` is not defined ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python tkinter return value from function used in command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099908/python-tkinter-return-value-from-function-used-in-command)

Comment: Sadly not, declaring it a global variable did not help neither using return().

Comment: That's literally the answer to the same question. Please post some code where you tried the Global variable approach and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling `setdate()` at any point so the `datechoisie1` is not being assigned. Call `setdate()` after your function.

However, generally assigning public variables inside functions is a pretty bad practice. If you really want to use a public variable, you should define it outside the function:

```
datechoisie1 = None

def setdate():
    datechoisie1 = cal.get_date()
    datechoisie1 = datechoisie.replace("/", "-")
    datechoisie1 = datechoisie.split('-')
    datechoisie1 = "-".join(reversed(datechoisie))
    mylabel.config(text="Date validée !")

setdate()
print(datechoisie1)
```

Comment: This is the problem, like I said my function setdate() is only called when the button "Validez la date" is pressed. If I put your datechoisie = None and then run my script, press the button to run the function and after that do a print of datechoisie, it is still "None"

Comment: @MaximeMichon Try it now. You had `datechoisie` instead of `datechoisie1` in the setdate.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have some kind of controller to manage you calendar and this kind of task would be implemented by it. Moreover the storage of the unique instance could be in the class itself as a singleton class :

```
class MyCalendarController:
    calendar = None
    curDate = None
    instance = None

    def __init__(self, calendar):
        if MyCalendarController.instance == None: 
            MyCalendarController.instance = self
        self.calendar = calendar

    def updateDate(self):
        if (self.calendar):
            self.curDate = self.calendar.get_date()

    @classmethod
    def sharedInstance(cls, calendar = None):
        if cls.instance == None: return cls(calendar)
        else: return cls.instance


# usage :
theCalendar = cal # this is your calendar 
MyCalendarController.sharedInstance(theCalendar).updateDate()
```