# How to return a value from one function to other using a button in tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button, return

So, I am working on a project in which there is a login screen with option to type in the id and password, but then in the GUI I want that when the "Enter" button is clicked, it should return the id to the function where is is called. My program is too long so I will give a small example to clear my point.

```
def func3():
       cred = func1()
       print(cred)
   def func1(): #Function for creating the GUI
       root = Tk()
       def func2(): #Function for getting the data and comparing with data from MySQL
           id = '123' #from entry widget
           flag = 0 
           # Comparison done: flag now equals 0 or 1
           if flag == 1: #When data matches
               return id
       btn = Button(master=root,text="Enter",command=func2) #This button should compare and return the id
       btn.pack()
```

Comment: What does `flag` do?

Comment: @ Cool Cloud It is just there to indicate if the id matched or not, if it matched, flag will be given the value 1 or otherwise remain 0. If flag = 1 next window will open or if flag = 0 , "Wrong credentials" will be displayed on the window with the help of a label.

Comment: @AST It is supposed to be like that, The actual comparison is done after the flag is declared(=0)

Comment: @AshmitRanjan the `retun` value will be of no use, it has been explained well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13101037/14094985)

Comment: Assign it in a variable and pass it onto another function or use `global varname`.

Comment: Can you please send the code for that in context of the code I posted in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have understood, you are looking for something like this

```py
from tkinter import *

def verify():
    global id_
    id_=id_entry.get()
    if id_==ID and pass_entry.get()==PASS:
        print('Success')
    else:
        print('Invalid')

root=Tk()

id_entry=Entry(root)
id_entry.pack()
pass_entry=Entry(root)
pass_entry.pack()
ent_button=Button(root,text='Enter',command=verify)
ent_button.pack()

ID='example'
PASS='password'

root.mainloop()
```

Using `retrun` will be pointless in this case since callbacks can't really return anything. It has been explained well in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13101037/14094985) post.

**UPDATE**

If you declare the variable as `global`, you can access it from anywhere in the code

```py
def verify():
    global id_
    id_=id_entry.get()
    if id_==ID and pass_entry.get()==PASS:
        success()
    else:
        print('Invalid')

def success():
    print(id_,'logged in successfully')
```

If you don't want to use `global` then you can pass it to the target function

```py
def verify():
    id_=id_entry.get()
    if id_==ID and pass_entry.get()==PASS:
        success(id_)
    else:
        print('Invalid')

def success(id_):
    print(id_,'logged in successfully')
```

Comment: Your code is correct for displaying message if the id and password match  but what i actually want to do is to take that _id variable you created and pass that to another function so that I know the id of the person who is logging in.

Comment: @AshmitRanjan Go ahead and pass to another function `function(id_)`, you won't need to make it global then. I have updated the answer.