# plot df outside function python tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

Could someone please tell me what is wrong with my code? I'm importing a csv using a file selector. I'd then like to plot the results but for some reason my code does not recognise the my dataframe.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


def import_csv_data():
    global v
    csv_file_path = askopenfilename()
    print(csv_file_path)
    v.set(csv_file_path)
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)
    return df
def plotting():
    fig1 = plt.figure('Flowrates')
    plt.title('Pressure vs. Flow')
    plt.xlabel('Pressure (bar)')
    plt.ylabel('Flow rate (L/min)')
    plt.axhline(y=300,color='r')
    plt.plot(df.iloc[:,0],df.iloc[:,1],label='ø2,0mm')

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text='File Path').grid(row=0, column=0)
v = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=v).grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Button(root, text='Browse Data Set',command=import_csv_data).grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Button(root, text='Close',command=root.destroy).grid(row=1, column=1)
tk.Button(root, text='Plot',command=plotting).grid(row=1,column=2)
root.mainloop()
```

my dataset is like so:

```
Wall pressure,flow rate (L.min-1) ›2mm,flow rate (L.min-1) ›2.1mm,flow rate (L.min-1) ›2.2mm,flow rate (L.min-1) ›2.3mm,flow rate (L.min-1) ›2.4mm,flow rate (L.min-1) ›2.5mm,flow rate (L.min-1) ›2.6mm
9,333,362,380,420,439,480,509
8.5,317,340,360,397,410,446,482
8,301,322,340,375,389,422,456
7.5,284,304,319,350,365,404,427
7,267,284,297,328,341,376,405
6.5,251,267,277,308,319,350,375
6,235,250,258,288,298,330,350
5.5,219,230,239,267,277,303,324
5,202,212,217,246,255,281,299
4.5,185,194,201,225,233,257,274
```

Any advice on how to get the 'plotting' function to work is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your `import_csv_data` function returns the dataframe, but the return is not stored in any variable. So your `plotting` function does not know the variable `df`. You can just make your `df` global.
This answer might help you as well: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099908/python-tkinter-return-value-from-function-used-in-command)

Comment: Thanks, that works and allows me to plot my results nicely. Are you aware of a way to do this without using global variables? Thanks for your help - much appreciated...

Comment: From the answer i linked, it seems like there are other possibilities, but they do not seem straight forward.