# python tkinter How to return value from function used in command

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

How do i get the return value filename in the `button_explore`  ?

Here is my code

```py
    def browseFiles():
       
       filename = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir = "/",title = "Select a File")
       
    
    label_file_explorer.configure(text="File Opened: "+filename)
    button_re = Button(window,text = "Browse Files",command = browseFiles)
```

I want to get the value of filename in command :

```
    button_explore = Button(window,text = " Ok ",command = ??? )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python tkinter return value from function used in command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099908/python-tkinter-return-value-from-function-used-in-command)

Comment: No isn't working

Comment: You could keep a static variable to hold the name.

Answer (score 0):

Re-wrote your script.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

top = tk.Tk()

def browseFiles():
   
   filename = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir = "/",title = "Select a File")
   label_file_explorer.configure(text="File Opened: "+filename)

label_file_explorer = tk.Label(top)
label_file_explorer.pack()
tk.Button(top,text = "Browse Files",command = browseFiles).pack()

top.mainloop()
```