# Returning File Path From tk GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I using tkinter and tkinterdnd2 to make a drag and drop GUI (I am using the below code). How do I return the value of the path name to use later? When I try to `print(get_path)` it returns this `<function get_path at 0x10cfa10d0>` or if I set a global varible = event I get `<tkinterdnd2.TkinterDnD.DnDEvent object at 0x164cef0d0>`

```
def get_path(event):
    pathLabel.configure(text=event.data)



root = TkinterDnD.Tk()
root.geometry("350x100")
root.title("Get file path")

nameVar = StringVar()

entryWidget = Entry(root)
entryWidget.pack(side=TOP, padx=5, pady=5)

pathLabel = Label(root, text="Drag and drop file in the entry box")
pathLabel.pack(side=TOP)

entryWidget.drop_target_register(DND_ALL)
entryWidget.dnd_bind("<<Drop>>", get_path)

Button(root, text="Close", command=root.destroy).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python tkinter return value from function used in command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099908/python-tkinter-return-value-from-function-used-in-command)

Comment: @LeeKaiXuan, no. It returns this object value: `<tkinterdnd2.TkinterDnD.DnDEvent object at 0x165456eb0>`

Comment: Since you have put the path in a label, you can get the path using `pathLabel["text"]`.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks, that worked. I can't believe I didn't realize that before asking